# INVALID_SENDER error at GCM registration

Tags: android, google-api

I am developing application where I want to implement push notification for that I am using GCM, I have registered my project on google console and using project ID as senderID for GCM registraton.

```
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this); //no error 
GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this); //no error          
final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);               
if (regId.equals("")) {
            GCMRegistrar.register(this, "********"); //after this.. 
                                       //onError method of GCMIntentService class
                                      //is triggered, there I am printing error
                                     //in log its saying INVALD_SENDER 
        }
```

I have given all required permissions in AndroidManifest.xml

I Have already referred following links

1) [Android GCM SENDER_ID, how to get it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294602/android-gcm-sender-id)
2) [Getting GCM Error: INVALID_SENDER occasionally in an app that has two GCM BroadcastReceivers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734335/getting-gcm-error-invalid-sender-occasionally-in-an-app-that-has-two-gcm-broadc) 3) [GCM Invalid sender error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15632924/gcm-invalid-sender-error) 4) http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

SENDER_ID = Project Number, I was using Project Id.. Project Number is available on console beside project id.

Comment: Or in the _google-services.json_ file that you should have placed in the root of your android project.

Answer (score 15):

Google has changed its layout. you can find **project_number** from here

select project -> *My Project*

click three dots -> *Project Information* -> *Project Number*

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU! Was going around in circles on these screens. Very poor layout.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example for push notifications, hope this helps:

```
private String SENDER_ID = "xxxxxxx";
private GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;

//somewhere else
gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
String msg = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
```

I recently got some service not available errors here so I also implemented a Broadcastreciever to recieve the regestration token.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
    if (data!=null){
        String regId = data.getString("registration_id");
    }
}
```

Comment: cant find GoogleCloudMessaging. I think you are using google-play-service_lib project. but I am using gcm.jar

Answer (score 0):

I got same error and found out that google login was not enabled in firebase console. After enabling it error was gone.

Check this image for reference:

[image]