# How do you find your Google Cast App ID (app_id) in the 2017 Google Play Developer Console?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-cast

I can no longer find the app_id that is required for the implementation of Google Play Services including Google Cast, In-app Billing, etc.

Example:

```
CastOptions castOptions = new CastOptions.Builder()
        .setReceiverApplicationId(context.getString(R.string.app_id))
        .build();
```

It used to be obtained via the Google Play Developer Console here:

[Google Play Developer Console 2014](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8M2os.jpg)

However Google recently released their new Play Console and things have been completely restructured:

[Google Play Developer Console April 2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STdtK.png)

Where is the app_id found now on the Play Developer Console?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23380711/invalid-sender-error-at-gcm-registration/36397562#36397562) answer

Comment: Sorry but that was not relevant. I'm implementing cast at the moment and cast is separate to these APIs. The app id is not the same as these API project ids as well, it is usually something generated from creating a play store instance, not an API project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ali-naddaf is correct, the application Id required for casting is not found on the Google Play Developer console. It is instead obtained by visiting https://cast.google.com/publish/#/overview and creating a new application. The default is a styled media receiver. Once you have created your application instance, you are given your application Id:

[Google Cast SDK Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFXKK.png)

You can then implement that application id in a strings xml file to set up your cast options:

```
CastOptions castOptions = new CastOptions.Builder()
    .setReceiverApplicationId(context.getString(R.string.app_id))
    .build();
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use the "Default Media Receiver" app id if you are okay with using the "Default Media Receiver".  This means you can't customize how the receiver looks when receiving your app, so no custom progress bar on the tv or something (as far as I understand).

So you can use one of the following ID's:

> •For Android apps: **CastMediaControlIntent.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID**
>
> •For Chrome apps: **chrome.cast.media.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APP_ID**
>
> •For iOS apps: **kGCKMediaDefaultReceiverApplicationID**

[Default app_id for Default Media Receiver](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/web_receiver#default_media_web_receiver)

Or, if you need that customization you can use one of the other receiver types (Styled/Custom), but for these you will need to register for a unique app_id for a small fee at the [Google Cast SDK Developer Console](https://cast.google.com/publish/#/overview).

Answer (score 1):

To register an App Id for Cast, go to this [page](https://cast.google.com/publish/#/overview).