# how to do chrome cast in JwPlayer for android

Tags: android, react-native, xamarin, jwplayer, chromecast

I'm trying to cast the videos playing on Jwplayer in near by devices like Tv, Laptop etc.

i followed this tutorial https://developer.jwplayer.com/jwplayer/docs/android-enable-casting-to-chromecast-devices

then on below code

```
CastOptions castOptions = new CastOptions.Builder()
//                .setReceiverApplicationId(context.getString(R.string.app_id))
                .setLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
                .build();
```

I didn't get `setReceiverApplicationId` as i don't have such a id.

So, i went here [How do you find your Google Cast App ID (app_id) in the 2017 Google Play Developer Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43533703/how-do-you-find-your-google-cast-app-id-app-id-in-the-2017-google-play-develop)  and decided not to pay before testing.

Then on Jw docs it is mentioned `setReceiverApplicationId() allows you to filter discovery results and to launch the receiver app when a cast session starts`

Since i don't need filters i commented that line.

Now i got a cast icon on xml. but when I tap it nothing is happening.

Please someone tell me

- Is app_id is necessary how to get it ?
- How to test the chrome casting ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `setReceiverApplicationId`, but you can use the [default receiver](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver#default_media_receiver) ID without paying for a developer account.

For Android, your code should look like

```java
CastOptions castOptions = new CastOptions.Builder()
                .setReceiverApplicationId(CastMediaControlIntent.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID)
                .setLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
                .build();
```